# Conjecture that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\big(\frac 1{q^{p_n}-1}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac 1{q^{p_n p_{n-k}}-1}\big)=\frac 1{q(q-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, proof-writing, prime-numbers, conjectures

I have had this conjecture for a while:

> Let $q\in\mathbb R\setminus [-1,1]$ and let $p_n$ be the $n^\text{th}$ prime. Then: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac 1{q^{p_n}-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac 1{q^{p_n p_{n-k}}-1}\bigg)=\frac 1{q(q-1)}$$

The sum looks like this when we expand it out:

> $$\frac 1{q^2-1}+\bigg(\frac 1{q^3-1}-\frac 1{q^{3\times 2}-1}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac 1{q^5-1}-\frac 1{q^{5\times 3}-1}-\frac 1{q^{5\times 2}-1}\bigg)+\cdots=\frac 1{q(q-1)}$$

I don't know how to show something like this. I can pull out a factor of $1/(q-1)$ but I don't think that will help.

Is this even true? I just had it written down in my notebook. (Sorry for not having any good proof attempts of my own.)

Comment: Why would you conjecture the right hand side to be $1/q(q-1)$ though?

Comment: @TravorLZH When I graphed the LHS on Desmos, it looked very similar to the graph of $y=\cfrac 1{x(x-1)}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formula is (closely) but not exactly true. Note that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl[ \frac{1}{q^{p_n} - 1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{q^{p_n p_k} - 1} \biggr]
&= \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{d \geq 1} \frac{1}{q^{d p_n}} - \sum_{n > k \geq 1} \sum_{d \geq 1} \frac{1}{q^{d p_n p_k}} \\
&= \sum_{l \geq 1} \biggl[ \sum_{p \mid l} 1 - \sum_{\substack{p p' \mid l \\ p < p'}} 1 \biggr] \frac{1}{q^l} \\
&= \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \biggl[ \omega(l) - \binom{\omega(l)}{2} \biggr] \frac{1}{q^l},
\end{align*}

where [$\omega(l) $ counts the number of *distinct* prime factors of $l$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function). Writing $a_l = \omega(l) - \binom{\omega(l)}{2}$ and noting that $k-\binom{k}{2} = 1$ for $k = 1, 2$, we get

$$ a_1 = 0, \qquad a_2 = a_3 = \ldots = a_{29} = 1, \qquad a_{30} = 0, \qquad \ldots $$

(This has to do with the fact that $30 = 2\cdot3\cdot5$ is the first positive integer with $3$ or more distinct prime factors.) Then this gives

$$ \frac{1}{q(q-1)} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl[ \frac{1}{q^{p_n} - 1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{q^{p_n p_k} - 1} \biggr]
= \sum_{l=2}^{\infty} \frac{1 - a_l}{q^l}
= \frac{1}{q^{30}} + \cdots. $$

In particular, the difference is quite small if $q$ is large. For example, if $q = 3$ then

$$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \biggl[ \frac{1}{3^{p_n} - 1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{3^{p_n p_k} - 1} \biggr] \approx 0.16666666666666180972\cdots, $$

which is quite close to but not the same as $\frac{1}{3(3-1)} = \frac{1}{6}$.